# Keyword as an argument for creating XML file

Tags: python, xml, arguments, keyword

So I want to create a XML-file, and one of the attributes that I have to add is called "from". When I want to add that I obviously get a "keyword can't be an expression" error. What do I have to do to make this work?

```
routes = ET.Element("routes")
for i,f in df.iterrows():
    flow = ET.SubElement(routes, "flow", id=str(i), from=f["source"], to = f["sink"])
```

The output should like this:

```
<routes>
  <flow id="0" from="A" to="B"></flow>
  <flow id="1" from="B" to="C"></flow>
  ...
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ET.SubElement` accepts an `attrib` kwarg especially for this usecase:

```
flow = ET.SubElement(routes, "flow", attrib={'id': str(i),
                                             'from': f["source"],
                                             'to': f["sink"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
flow = ET.SubElement(
    routes, 
    "flow", 
     **{
        "id": str(i), 
        "from": f["source"], 
        "to": f["sink"]
     }
)
```